# 500 internal server error when hosted in godaddy windows based server

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5 PHP framework and when I upload to godaddy I get the following PHP error

```
Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in G:\PleskVhosts\telligentts.com\httpdocs\audit1\public\index.php on line 50
```

Comment: Can you please provide some more background? Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask if you are unsure of how to ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel 5 
[laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0)

Laravel 5 requirements
PHP >= 5.4, PHP < 7

Check godaddy PHP version and update php version [php supported versions](http://php.net/supported-versions.php)

Comment: godaddy PHP version 5.4 i think it will support laravel.